# OSX app for graphs with paths finding function

Tags: macos, unix, graph, osx-lion

I need an app where I can first make graph with directed lines between objects and then find ways from one object to another. Actually I need to find all ways from object to object (not only shortest).
It could be online app or OSX application. Also, if you know any on linux or windows app, it also could help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try building a graph and then doing a "depth-first-search" on it to get started. Google will do the rest.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search
http://merganser.math.gvsu.edu/david/reed03/projects/haithcock/dfs.html

You'll need to code something up yourself, the application you describe is fairly specialized.